# Looking for a piece regarding the relationship between subject and object (by Schopenhauer?)

Tags: metaphysics, reference-request

I am desperately looking for a piece I've read years ago on the internet. It is written as a conversation (literally) between the subject and the object. The quintessence is that neither can exist without the other. I think it is by Schopenhauer. However, I am not 100 percent sure. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Would you remember how long it was? I assume only a few pages if it was on the internet. Do you remember anything about the title? Just trying to probe for more keyword hints to help search for it. Welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A short piece of dialogue](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_World_as_Will_and_Representation/First_Half) between *Subject* an *Matter* appears at the end of the Supplement to book1 of The World as Will and Representation, chap. 1.

> As a forcible conclusion of this important and difficult discussion I
>   shall now personify these two abstractions, and present them in a
>   dialogue after the fashion of Prabodha Tschandro Daya. It may also
>   be compared with a similar dialogue between *matter* and *form* in the  "Duodecim Principia Philosophies, " of Raymund Lully. (p.181-3)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I think that should be it, altough I remember it to be longer in text.  Maybe my memory tricks me. I read it almost 10 years ago. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some relevant words.

"In the Foundation of Morality, Schopenhauer asks the question: How is it that a human being can so participate in the pain and danger of another that, forgetting his own self-protection, he moves spontaneously to the other’s rescue? How is it that what we think of as the first law of nature - self-protection - is suddenly dissolved and another law asserts itself spontaneously? Schopenhauer answers: this is the breakthrough of a metaphysical truth - that you and other are one, and that separateness is a secondary effect of the way our minds experience the world in the frame of time and space. At the metaphysical level, we are all manifestations of that consciousness and energy which is the consciousness and energy of life. This is Schopenhauer:

“The experience that dissolves the distinction between the I and the Not I … underlies the mystery of compassion, and stands, in fact, for the reality of which compassion is the prime expression. That experience, therefore, must be the metaphysical ground of ethics and consist simply in this: that one individual should recognise in another, himself in his own true being … Which is the recognition for which the basic formula is the standard Sanskrit expression, ‘Thou art that’, tat tvam asi.”

John Mathews
Joseph Campbell and the Grail Myth

"[P]ersonality and causality exist in this temporal, sensory, comprehensible world. But the better consciousness within me lifts me up into a world where neither personality, nor subject and object, exist any more."

Schopenhauer-
Manuscript Remains